# Using selected field value in condition of MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 Tables from which Im fetching records using following query.

```
SELECT es.name,es.location,e.num_days as days
FROM event_schedule es,events e
WHERE es.owner_id=1 AND es.event_id=e.id AND (es.date_of_service BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 DAY)"
```

In an given query Im fetching all the schedule events which are in next 4 days. Query works okay. What my problem is 'INTERVAL 4 DAY' this value is supposed to be from table 'event' itself. That means value of a field (e.num_days as days) from same query.

Any idea how can I get this done ?

Comment: Have you tried with a subquery?

Comment: what's the problem of using it directly on the query? `INTERVAL num_days DAY`, example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9865/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, learn proper join syntax.

You can use a variable in place of the `4`.  So try this:

```
SELECT es.name,es.location,e.num_days as days
FROM event_schedule es join
     events e
     on es.owner_id=1 AND es.event_id=e.id AND
        (es.date_of_service BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL e.num_days DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. But why it didn't worked when I use days instead of es.num_days.

Comment: @Mahendra . .. Because `days` is an alias provided in the `select` clause.  The `from` clause is evaluated before these aliases are set.  You can only use select aliases in `group by`, `having`, and `order by` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $val contains the value you want

```
SELECT es.name,es.location,e.num_days as days FROM event_schedule es,events e WHERE es.owner_id=1 AND es.event_id=e.id AND (es.date_of_service BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL $val DAY)"
```

Comment: no this is not what Im asking for. I want es.num_days to user insted of static value 4 and in a same query. No PHP value can be used.